# How to get user attributes using adminGetUserRequest in cognito

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get the user attributes from cognito using AdminGetUserRequest, the following is my code:

```
public class getUserDetails {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String app_client_id ="xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String app_client_secret ="xxxxxxxxxxx";
        String user_pool_id ="xxxxxxxxx";
        String region = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        String AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        String AWS_SECRET_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        AWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
        AWSCognitoIdentityProvider client = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();
        AdminGetUserRequest adminGetUserRequest = new AdminGetUserRequest()
                .withUserPoolId(user_pool_id)
                .withUsername("testUser");

        try {
            AdminGetUserResult adminGetUserResult = client.adminGetUser(adminGetUserRequest);
            System.out.println(adminGetUserResult.getUserAttributes());
        }catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("User not found");
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine and I am getting the user, but the attribute values are listed as ***Sensitive Data Redacted***. The output I am getting is the following

```
[{Name: sub,Value: ***Sensitive Data Redacted***}, {Name: email_verified,Value: ***Sensitive Data Redacted***}, {Name: email,Value: ***Sensitive Data Redacted***}]
```

How do I get the values that are listed as ***Sensitive Data Redacted***. I don't have any access tokens, I just have the username to retrieve these values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe this is just a default implementation of `toString` method of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidp/model/AttributeType.html to prevent unintentional log of sensitive data.

Try to explicitly ask for `getValue` and I believe you will get your value.